# How to find the max frequency at a certain db in a fft signal

Tags: fft, frequency

I am processing some audio files and I would like to find out the maximum frequency in the spectrum (fft) given a certain magnitude range (in may case: maximum magnitude to -60db).

How can I achieve that?

I know how to calculate the maximum frequency of an fft signal:

```
peak_index = np.argmax(np.abs(fft))
peak_freq = fft_freq[peak_coefficient] * sample_rate
```

how I can add the db level range in this calculation?

Comment: Are you looking for the maximum frequency or the frequency for which the magnitude is the maximum?

Comment: Hi, and welcome here! It's really not quite clear what you mean with "the maximum frequency in the spectrum(fft) at a certain dB level". Please explain a bit more what that means!

Comment: thanks for your comments and yes, I will explain it more clearly: I would like to know the maximum frequency, in a certain magnitude range (maximum magnitude to -60db for my concern).
I will edit my question too.

Comment: to be clear-- if the magnitude of a bin was above -60 dB, then you would exclude this from being reported, or do you mean maximum magnitude above -60 dB? Also dB to what: dB below full scale (dBFS)?

Comment: I would like to consider all the bins above -60dB and discard the ones below -60dB. and yes, I mean dBFS.

Comment: but if you're doing a maximum operation, then lower bins (assuming there is at least a single one above your threshold) don't matter anyway: "Find the largest number not smaller than 4 in (1, 3, 5, 7)" is identical to "find the largest number in (1, 3, 5, 7)". So is this only about the case where there might be *no* magnitude larger than -60 dB in your signal?

Comment: you are quite right, I think I was again not so clear in my explanation, so I will try again:
I would like to find out the highest frequency in a given amplitude (0 to -60db). it could be that there are higher frequencies at lower amplitudes, but I want to exclude that.

Comment: I don't understand that, this is even less clear. Because how can something < -60 be > -60?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you're asking, but I think this does something like it.

[image: Example]

Regarding how magnitude relates to dB: decibels are a *relative* scale, so you need to decide what it's relative to. Since you agreed in the comments that it was [dBFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBFS), I took the largest value in the data (e.g. `np.max(data)`).

With that in mind, then the dB scale is:

```
fft_db = 20*np.log10(np.abs(fft)/np.max(np.abs(fft)))
```

---

## Python code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fft_db = np.random.random(100)*100 - 130 
fft_db[80:100] = -130

fft_db_flip = np.flip(fft_db)

requested_value = len(fft_db) - np.argmax(fft_db_flip > -60) - 1

plt.plot(fft_db)
plt.plot(requested_value, fft_db[requested_value],'r.')
plt.plot([0,100],[-60,-60],'g:')
```

Comment: thank you! this looks pretty good and it is exactly what I was trying to do. one thing it still unclear though, how does the magnitude levels relate to dBs?

Comment: @user1889342 Added an explanation. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! @user1889342 If this answers the question, please select the check-mark and/or upvote the answer!